# How to display selected option get by id when update a data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display a selected value in select option tag, with specific id,
I have a post table

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| post_id | post_title  | post_content  | category_id |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 1       | Title One   | Content One   | 1           |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 2       | TitleTwo    | Content Two   | 1           |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 3       | Title Three | Content Three | 2           |
+---------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

then I have a category table

```
+-------------+----------------+
| category_id | category       |
+-------------+----------------+
| 1           | Category One   |
+-------------+----------------+
| 2           | Category Two   |
+-------------+----------------+
| 3           | Category Three |
+-------------+----------------+
```

I display the category with select option tag

the controller add

```
function add(){
    if ($this->input->post('submit'){
        $data = array(
            'post_title' => $this->input->post('post_title'),
            'post_content' => $this->input->post('post_content'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'));
        $this->db->insert('post_table',$data);
    }
    $data[cats] = $this->db->get(category_table)->result();
    $this->load->view('view_add_post');
}
```

view add,

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/post/add">
    <input type="text" name="post_title">
    <textarea name="post_content"></textare>
    <select name="category_id">
        <?php foreach ($cats as $category) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category->category_id ?>"><?php echo $category->category?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

controller edit

```
function edit($id){
    $data['post'] = $this->db->get_where('post_table' array('post_id',$id))->row();
    $data['cats'] = $this->db->get('category_table)->result();
    $this->load->view('view_edit_post',$data)
}
```

edit view

Here is the problem I want to display the category on dropdown select option, where the selected is the first I input, for example I already input the post with category id is 1 then when I edit the category 1 in select option is automatically selected, how to do that?

```
<select name="category_id">
    <?php foreach ($cats as $category) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category->category_id ?>"><?php echo $category->category?>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

// the selected option is automatically
```

Sorry my english is bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this code

```
<select name="category_id">
<?php foreach ($cats as $category) { ?>
<option <?php if($category->category_id == "your desired id"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $category->category_id ?>"><?php echo $category->category?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I actually added a hint for you as your question was not so clear.

You have to put your desired id to match both for selected category

Comment: How stupid I am, It's quite simply, thanks anyway, sorry my english is very bad, I don't understand what I'm write anyway, hahahah
I love you sir.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Mr. Uzair do you have an email? I have a problem again, please help me! How to show the selected menu, if a multiple?

Comment: kindly add a new question and tag me there like @yuliantosaparudin i have taged you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selected=""` by using this condition in `option`:

```
<select name="category_id"> 

<?php foreach ($cats as $category) { ?>    
<option <?=( $category->category == $post[0]->category_id ? 'selected=""' : '')?> value="<?php echo $category->category_id ?>">

<?php echo $category->category?> <?php } ?> 
</option>
</select>
```

In your example you are missing the closing tag `</option>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category:</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="roomtype" required>
         <option disabled selected value>Category</option>
          <?php   foreach($roomstype as $roomstypedatas) { ?>
                               
 <option value="<?php echo $roomstypedatas['id']?>"
     <?php if($editroomsdata['roomtype']==$roomstypedatas['id']){ echo "selected"; } ?> >
     <?php echo $roomstypedatas['type']?>
 </option>  
          <?php  } ?>
          </select>
         </div>
```